# How to normalize an array column in a dataframe

Tags: apache-spark, dataframe, apache-spark-sql

I'm using spark 2.2. and I want to normalize each value in the fixed-size array.

input

```
{"values": [1,2,3,4]}
```

output

```
{"values": [0.25, 0.5, 0.75, 1] }
```

For now, I'm using a *udf* :

```
val f = udf { (l: Seq[Double]) =>
  val max = l.max
  l.map(_ / max)
}
```

Is there a way to avoid udf (and associated performance penalty).

Comment: @vaquarkhan The question is not the same. Morreover, I'd like to avoid adding a dependency to MLLib and converting back and forth to RDD.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've come up with an optimized version of my udf, which performs in-place updates.

```
  val optimizedNormalizeUdf = udf { (l: mutable.WrappedArray[Double]) =>
    val max = l.max
    (0 until n).foreach(i => l.update(i, l(i) / max))
    l
  }
```

I've written a benchmark to check performance of the solution proposed by user8838736. Here are the results.

```
[info] Benchmark                         Mode  Cnt    Score    Error  Units
[info] NormalizeBenchmark.builtin        avgt   10  140,293 ± 10,805  ms/op
[info] NormalizeBenchmark.udf_naive      avgt   10  104,708 ±  7,421  ms/op
[info] NormalizeBenchmark.udf_optimized  avgt   10   99,492 ±  7,829  ms/op
```

**Conclusion : The *udf* is the most performant solution in this case.**

PS : For those who are interested, the source code of the benchmark is here : https://github.com/YannMoisan/spark-jmh

Answer (score 2):

Lets say that number of records in each array is `n`

```
val n: Int
```

Then

```
 import org.apache.spark.sql.functions._


df
  .withColumn("max", greatest((0 until n).map(i => col("value")(i)): _*))
  .withColumn("values", array((0 until n).map(i => col("value")(i) / col("max")): _*))
```