# How to perform a dotProduct between 2 columns in a dataframe

Tags: apache-spark, apache-spark-sql

I'm using Spark 2.2. and I have a `DataFrame` with 2 `ArrayType` columns of fixed-size.

I want to perform a dot product between those columns.

I'm using a *udf* but I wonder if there is a better way ?

```
val dotProduct = udf((l1: Seq[Double], l2: Seq[Double]) => l1.zip(l2).map(t => t._1 * t._2).sum)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've tried 2 other strategies :

without using UDF

```
val dotProduct =
  (0 until nb)
    .map(i => $"c1"(i) * $"c2"(i))
    .reduce(_ + _)
```

It was way slower.

with UDF, but avoid creating intermediate collections.

```
val dotProoduct = udf((l1: Seq[Double], l2: Seq[Double]) => {
  var b = 0.0
  val these = l1.iterator
  val those = l2.iterator
  while (these.hasNext && those.hasNext)
    b += these.next() * those.next()
  b
})
```

I've improved performance by a factor 2 \o/

Answer (score 0):

UDF are a good solution here and in all of your other questions:

- [How to perform an element-wise division in a dataframe](https://stackoverflow.com/q/46515834/6910411)
- [How to normalize an array column in a dataframe](https://stackoverflow.com/q/46513246/6910411)

For fixed size arrays, you can access elements by index, but otherwise there is no alternative.

Comment: for fixed size arrays, what is the more performant : udf or accessing element by index ?